# How to require new for Error with command-line jshint

Tags: javascript, jshint

Entering this code on [www.jshint.com](http://www.jshint.com/) produces the validation message "Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor":

```
/*jshint globalstrict: true*/
/*jshint newcap:true*/

'use strict';

function main() {
  var x = Error('x');
  return x;
}

main();
```

But the same code when validated with command-line jshint does not produce any warning:

```
fernando@fernando-i7-mint /tmp1050 $ ls -la 
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 fernando fernando 4096 Jun 27 11:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 28 root     root     4096 Jun 27 11:23 ..
-rw-rw-rw-  1 fernando fernando  132 Jun 27 11:06 test.js

fernando@fernando-i7-mint /tmp1050 $ cat test.js 
/*jshint globalstrict: true*/
/*jshint newcap:true*/

'use strict';

function main() {
  var x = Error('x');
  return x;
}

main();

fernando@fernando-i7-mint /tmp1050 $ jshint --version
jshint v2.5.1

fernando@fernando-i7-mint /tmp1050 $ jshint test.js 
fernando@fernando-i7-mint /tmp1050 $
```

How to ensure that validating via command-line will produce the expected warnings?

**Update:** The validation works for custom constructors, but not for the built-in `Error` function. So the question is: what configuration options are necessary so that this violation (calling `Error` without `new`) will be shown via command line?

Comment: The two JSHints may have different defaults. You need to explicitly configure the settings to warn about errors, not expect it to work the same everywhere. If after configuring, it doesn't work, then there's a bug somewhere

Comment: This is the point of this question: how to configure the settings to warn about this error? What setting is missing so that `newcap` warnings will be shown in the command line?

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying now. I'm messing around with it locally

Comment: I'm not sure why the website picks it up, but the problem seems to be with specifically using `Error`. Try making you own constructor function (doesn't need code in the body), and simply calling it (without `new`). My commandline JSHint will complain. But as soon as I take it out and leave the `Error()` call, it's happy.

Comment: It's weird that it's fixating on `Error`. I tried `var y = Array();` and it complained about that. But something with `Error` isn't causing problems. I wonder if it's a bug, or intended...

Comment: Thanks @Ian. It seems indeed that the issue is related to using Error. It just happens that I'd like this specific warning to be shown (i.e., using Error without new). I'll update the question with the new information.

Comment: I decided to create a new issue in their GitHub repo anyways: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1744